# How to select from a dropdown with Selenium WebDriver 3.8 for C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a value from a dropdown select item with Selenium. However, I cannot find the Select or SelectElement objects within 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI' in C#?

Has this functionality been removed?

Is there an alternate way to select an option from the select element on a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelectElement will be available by installing the Selenium.Support (version 3.8.0) NuGet package.